# Decrypting cryptography fernet encoding to check if the input is the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a pin encoded using the cryptography fernet library, I'm trying to take input from the user and check if it is the same as the pin in the file, but I need to decrypt it to read it and I can't figure out how.

PS. I have the pin encoded in a .key file, is that okay?

Here is the error I'm getting

```
raise TypeError("{} must be bytes".format(name))
TypeError: token must be bytes
```

And here's my code

```
def get_pin():
    pid_input = input("Enter your pin :  ")
    with open("PID.key", 'r') as pid_file:
        for line in pid_file.readlines():
            data = line.rstrip()
            pid = data.split()
            pid_decoded = pid_file.read(fer.decrypt(pid)).encode()
    if pid_input == pid_decoded:
        pass
    else:
        exit()
```

Comment: Why not just encrypt the user's given pin with the same encryption logic used to encrypt the master and compare the results, thus the processing logic never has the unencrypted pin in the clear?

Comment: I have tried this at first by just using the + operator but I don't know if it just doesn't work  or I just did something wrong, it accepts any pin

Comment: I am not absolutely sure, but there seems to be two issues with your code. First, to decrypt a token you need the original key used to encrypt the data.  This key is a member of the fernet.key class.  I don't see where you are utilizing this key., Second, the token resulting from a fernet encryption is binary, you seem to be attempting to read this token from the pid_file as text i.e.```with open("PID.key", 'r') as pid_file``` assuming you have properly encoded the original pid as a text string, before saving to pid_file, you need to convert the string back to binary.